# Ссылка с class="btn" больше не ссылка

Tags: html, ссылки, вёрстка, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь стилизировать ссылку под кнопку, используя css класс btn bootstrap'a, но ссылка с таким классом перестает быть ссылкой, и при клике по ней не происходит вообще ничего.

```
<a href="/page" class="btn">link to page</a>
```

Можно, конечно, решить это при помощи javascript, но, по-моему, это какой-то сильно варварский способ в данном случае. Что-то мне подсказывает, что я не первый с такой проблемой. и искренне верю, что мне здесь кто-нибудь поможет вернуть ссылке свойства ссылки. Помогите! )

Comment: @fogipoziw выложите где нибудь эту страничку и ее запчасти. Думаю без волшебства тут не обошлось.

Comment: @silksOfTheSoul, я понял, что это не норма для bootstrap, а с внутрепроектной магией я уж сам разберусь, т.к. файлов там не мало.
Спасибо за время, потраченное на меня.

Comment: @fogipoziw да не за что:) Может, еще знающие люди подойдут подскажут...

Удачи вам.

Comment: @fogipoziw, ссылка как ссылка. В чем проблема ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Link</a>
```

[Официальная документация](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)

Получилось?

Comment: @silksOfTheSoul, нет, ноль реакции

Comment: мне ее как раз нужно сделать не кнопкой, запускающей функцию, а именно ссылкой, позволяющей перейти на другую страницу

Comment: @fogipoziw в таком случае проверьте, подключен ли css файл bootstrap
через менеджер ресурсов найдите эту css и откройте адрес в браузере, если файл на месте вы видеть содержимое проверьте отдаваемый заголовок css файла. Если сервак отдает вместо type css, type text -- то это возможная причина проблемы.

Comment: @silksOfTheSoul, Content-Type:text/css. На что вообще это может влиять?

Comment: У старых браузеров проблем вроде не будет, но на новых есть ограничения безопасности. если указанный тип файла не соответствует content-type то браузер его не ест и пишет ошибку в консоли. Помница такое случается, если просто так подключать css с гитхаба. сталкивался с этим когда делал тему для tumblr.

Comment: @silksOfTheSoul, но в таком же случае у меня вообще не будут стили работать? тут же весь сайт сверстан на bootstrap - все в норме, в консоле ошибок по css никаких

Comment: @fogipoziw хм... логично.
хорошо... давайте посмотрим код. возможно какой то яваскрипт блокирует нажатие. Сталкивался с этим в flat-ui  в горизонтальном меню. там элемент ссылка не работает если из него предпологается выпадающий подуровень.